# Rails mailer views in separated directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have small organizatoric issue, in my application I have 3 mailer User_mailer, prduct_mailer, some_other_mailer and all of them store their views in app/views/user_mailer ...

I will want to have a subdirectory in /app/views/ called mailers and put all in the folders user_mailer, product_mailer and some_other_mailer.

Thanks,

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I so agree with this organization strategy!

And from Nobita's example, I achieved it by doing:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "whatever@whatever.com"
  default :template_path => '**your_path**'

  def whatever_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = "http://whatever.com"
    mail(:to => user.email,
         :subject => "Welcome to Whatever",
         )
  end
end
```

It is Mailer-specific but not too bad!

Comment: `default template_path: "mailers/#{self.name.underscore}"`. In given example, it would look for templates in: `/app/views/mailers/user_mailer/`

Comment: Looks nice. I may change this!

Comment: Woah!  @faraz's answer is even better! :D

Comment: This can be done once in `ApplicationMailer` instead, see @vemv  answer

Comment: @OdedNiv 1 year later, but yes - `default template_path: -> { "mailers/#{self.class.name.underscore}" }`. It needs to be a lambda to be called when the mail is being sent instead of when the class is loaded. Added `self.class` since it's now an instance variable (at the time of call) instead of a class method (at load).

Answer (score 40):

You should really create an `ApplicationMailer` class with your defaults and inherit from that in your mailers:

```
# app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  append_view_path Rails.root.join('app', 'views', 'mailers')
  default from: "Whatever HQ <hq@whatever.com>"
end

# app/mailers/user_mailer.rb
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def say_hi(user)
    # ...
  end
end

# app/views/mailers/user_mailer/say_hi.html.erb
<b>Hi @user.name!</b>
```

This lovely pattern uses the same inheritance scheme as controllers (e.g. `ApplicationController < ActionController::Base`).

Comment: See http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActionView/ViewPaths/ClassMethods#append_view_path-instance_method

Comment: This is better in design than the accepted answer of setting template path on every mailer, but it doesn't handle lazy locale lookup. @vemv answer is the best

Comment: Can you clarify? I've been using this with different locales for years now without any problems.

Answer (score 14):

I had some luck with this in 3.1

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  ...
  append_view_path("#{Rails.root}/app/views/mailers")
  ...
end
```

Got deprecation warnings on template_root and RAILS_ROOT

Comment: Worked for me in Rails 4.0

Comment: ```append_view_path Rails.root.join('app', 'views', 'mailers')```

Comment: `prepend_view_path` is probably better so the view lookup code doesn't have to look through all other directories before coming to the mailer-only directory to find the template.

Answer (score 14):

If you happen to need something really flexible, inheritance can help you.

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def self.inherited(subclass)
    subclass.default template_path: "mailers/#{subclass.name.to_s.underscore}"
  end

end
```

Comment: Exactly, `append_view_path` doesn't handle lazy locale lookup

Comment: FWIW, `default template_path: -> { "mailers/#{self.class.name.underscore}" }` is the same, slightly cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

You can put the templates wherever you want, but you will have to specify it in the mailer. Something like this:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "whatever@whatever.com"

  def whatever_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = "http://whatever.com"
    mail(:to => user.email,
         :subject => "Welcome to Whatever",
         :template_path => '**your_path**',
         )
  end
end
```

Take a look at [2.4 Mailer Views](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

#### Easy Solution: Specify Path in `ApplicationMailer`

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base      
  layout 'mailer'
  prepend_view_path "app/views/mailers"  # <---- dump your views here
end
```