# Rails mailer and mailer views in subfolder not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I have a mailer that I can see in my log is getting sent, but the email body does not contain anything from the mailer view.

It's due to the fact that I've put things in subfolders and i've tried using `:template_path` in my `mail` function but to no avail.

app/mailers/marketing/marketing_mailer.rb

```
class Marketing::MarketingMailer < ActionMailer::Base

    require 'mail'
    address = Mail::Address.new "test@example.com" # ex: "john@example.com"
    address.display_name = "Text" # ex: "John Doe"
    # Set the From or Reply-To header to the following:
    address.format # returns "John Doe <john@example.com>"
    default from: address

    # Sends an email when someone fills out the contact form
    def contact(name, email, message)
        @name = name
        @email = email
        @message = message
        mail(:subject => "Test", :to => 'test@example.com', :reply_to => @email) # <== I've tried using :template_path => 'marketing', 'marketing/marketing_mailer', etc, but none worked.
    end
end
```

/app/views/marketing/marketing_mailer/contact.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Name: <%= @name %></p>
    <p>Email: <%= @email %></p>
    <p>Message: <%= @message %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I noticed that devise has mailer views inside /views/devise/mailers/... so I know it's possible, but i'm not sure how.

Comment: It depends on the rails version you are using. Please mention your Rails version

Comment: Similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017907/rails-mailer-views-in-separated-directory

Comment: @SatyaKalluri I saw that answer and tried the template_path. Some of the other answers seem to throw deprecation warnings and stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came back to this project today and it seems to be finding the template today no problem without having to specify the template_path.

As sad as this is, apparently all I needed to do was stop and restart my server for my mailer views to get picked up. Since other views get picked up without stopping and starting my server, i'm very surprised by this.

Comment: This behaviour I know from view templates. A template gets looked up but at that time, it's not present yet. The server doesn't find it, but remembers the fact that it's not there. Then won't look for it again until the next restart, even though you added it.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried mail with {:template_path => 'marketing/marketing_mailer, :template_name =>'contact'} ?

The template name probably expects the namespace in the filename somehow

Answer (score 3):

Does it work without the template Rendering

```
   class Marketing::MarketingMailer < ActionMailer::Base
   def welcome_email(user, email_body)
     mail(to: user.email,
     body: email_body,
     content_type: "text/html",
     subject: "Already rendered!")
   end
   end
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your file is in the format of `.html.erb`, you may have to specify that you want to use this format. Like so:

```
mail(:subject => "Test", :to => 'test@example.com', :reply_to => @email) do
  format.html
end
```

Usually, your template should just be picked up automatically, since the names match up, but there's probably a second file by the same name ending in `.text.erb` or some other thing that gets in the way of template look-up.

**EDIT1** (wild guess)
Aside from template lookup issues, the only other source of problems I can imagine, would be your instance variables. Maybe `@message` is supposed to be something else and you're interfering with internals, so renaming it might help. According to the code on apidock, mail is using `@variables` at certain places. This is far fetched though, I admit.

**EDIT2** (explanation of the problem faced here)
The behavior behind the actual problem - not finding a new template until server restart - works like this:

A template gets looked up but at that time, it's not present yet. The server doesn't find it, but remembers the fact that it's not there. Then won't look for it again until the next restart, even though you added it.

So, restarting will fix this.

*Have you tried turning it off and on again?*

Comment: `.html.erb` is the default that is expected when creating a mailer with the rails generator http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: did you try it though?

Comment: @Catfish I also added another hunch, though far fetched.